# Rails timezone select doesn't show DST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

In my user edit view I have the following select: `<%= f.time_zone_select :timezone %>`
So that users can save their own timezone to tailor the dates on our app.

However we've noticed that during DST which is the case at the time of this posting the select is still showing `(GMT+00:00) London` instead of `UTC+00:01` or `BST`.

Is this an option in Rails to show the correct timezone? Or is what is currently being show actually correct instead?

Comment: I'm not certain enough to answer with regard to Rails, but generally any list of time zone display names that shows an offset tends to show the *standard* offset, which as you pointed out may be different than the *current* offset.  (A more prominent example is the UI around picking a time zone built in to Windows.)  If you desire different behavior, you may need to create the select control yourself, rather than relying on the helper.